# How to generate features of data in my case so that I can use some tools like LinearRegression to predict?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, regression, data-mining

I am new in this field. I want to analyze, as a retailer, which customer bought my goods during my promotion would become a loyal customer. I have a list of user action during the promotion and user information and also a list of customer&merchant pair whose customer is known as loyal to the merchant. I still have another list of customer&merchant pair, and I need to predict if they would have a loyal relationship. The data is quite huge I just put some lines here.

```
user_id item_id cat_id  merchant_id brand_id    time_stamp  action_type
168006  348194  544     692         517         625         0
168006  768080  984     706         1060        1016        1
168006  810877  284     692         517         625         2

user_id#merchant_id prob
7562#3571           0
7562#4784           0
7562#3404           1
```

cat_id: product category
action_type: on behalf of something like add to cart, purchase, add to favorite

I think I can use something like sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression to predict the `prob` item in my predict list, by making every user#perchant pair as one item. Here the `prob` means loyal if 1 and not loyal if 0, in the new list, `prob` would be a float num.

I still have a list of user_information which is quite easy to deal with which I won't put it here. But I don't know how to generate the features from my user action list. Could you give me some idea? In fact, I still don't know if I should use LinearRegression or maybe better tool available?

Answer (score 0):

It's a great question.  What you've captured here is that you have some data (user actions associated with merchants) and you want to translate that into an insight (probability of user having more action with a merchant).

This problem is very similar to Netflix's problem.  They have viewers (like your customers) and movies (like your merchants or products) and they need to know what movies a viewer will like before they watch the movie.  This is a recommender system.

There is a good course on this topic here : https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-recommenders

From a conceptual point of view, what you are looking to do is to learn the preference vectors for each customer and description vectors for each merchant.  The preference and description vectors combine to determine the recommendation.

If I was going to implement this in a Neural Net I'd do the following:

1 hot encode the customers and connect that in a feed forward net to a few nodes.  If you think there are 5 distinct dimensions of preference, then use 5 nodes.  Perhaps as many as 10.

1 hot encode the merchants and connect that in a feed forward net to a few nodes.  If you think there are 5 distinct dimension of merchant value, then use 5 nodes.  Perhaps as low as 3.

These two smaller layers on top of the 1 hot encoding of the customer and merchant make a dimensionality reduction layer for the merchant and customer and will encode their preferences.

Now feed the two nets another small layer (perhaps 5 nodes again) and then to two output nodes ( 1 for doesn't fit and 1 for does fit ).

Train the whole configuration on your training data.  At the end you'll have learnt the preferences of your customers and description of your merchants and how they match up conceptually.

When you have a new customer or merchant your task is to discover their vector, not recalculate everything.  You can use technology like K-means to find customers like that customer or merchants like a merchant.